# SQL Server Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am getting this error when I am checking the logs of my application:

> [Databases] Exception : dbi.integrity-error, [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK__tblRaw201131411__13D55980'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.tblRaw201131411'. in EXEC
>
> [Databases] Exception : dbi.integrity-error, [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK__tblRaw201131412__407DE2C5'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.tblRaw201131412'. in EXEC
>
> File "mssqlinterface.py", line 951, in executeSQLStatement

How to fix this error?

My application is using a `SQL Server 2005` Database.

Comment: What is the pk in your table? Is it autogenerated or not?

Answer (score 6):

You can fix this error by not trying to insert rows with a duplicate primary key.

*How* you do that depends a great deal on your application, the details of which you haven't provided (lines 900 through 960 of `mssqlinterface.py` would be a good start with a special marker on line 951).

Perhaps you're trying to insert when you should update. Perhaps the code that sets the primary key value is deficient in some manner.

The possibilities are literally (and I mean that in a very figurative sense), endless.

Answer (score 0):

don't insert the same value into a primary key column twice...?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Primary key violation you are trying to insert something which will make the data used by the primary key not unique.

1) You can simply not do this, make sure you dont add duplicate PK data

2) Maybe you need to update your primary key to be a compound key (Key uses 2 or more columns) so the data used by the PK can be unique.

3) If you are manually entering the data you are using as your PK maybe add another column named ID to this table (if appropriate) and set it to automatically increment itself then make this your PK, thus your PK will always be unique.

4) Remove the PK (this is generally a really bad idea)

Without more data it really is hard to offer a solution but at a glance these 4 options are what I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Identity column doesn't guarantee uniqueness of ids.
Here's some code to reproduce the error, and a possible solution:

```
CREATE TABLE atest (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY , val VARCHAR(10));

insert atest values ('a')
insert atest values ('b')
insert atest values ('c')
insert atest values ('d')
insert atest values ('e')

delete atest  where id < 4

select * from atest
--4 d
--5 e

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('atest', RESEED, 0);

insert atest values ('aa')
insert atest values ('bb')
insert atest values ('cc')

select * from atest
--1 aa
--2 bb
--3 cc
--4 d
--5 e

-- Here comes the error!
insert atest values ('dd')
-- Oops!


-- Here's the Solution:
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('atest', RESEED);

-- Try again...
insert atest values ('dd')

select * from atest
--1 aa
--2 bb
--3 cc
--4 d
--5 e
--6 dd

--All good!
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are trying to import a file that has duplicate records. Generally I import those to a staging table and do a data clean up to get rid of them before importing to a production table. You could also remove the duplicate records through an SSIS pacakage dataflow. Most important is to find out why the file has duplicate records and what that means in terms of the data model you are trying to import to. For instance suppose you were importing a roster fo sales reps who each have a territory. Assume your table considers the terrtory to be unique and thus made it the PK. Then you get a new client and you get a PK error because they have two reps who share a territory. Just deleting the records won't do you any good (those reps would not be able to access your system), you now need to fix your application to handle reps who share terrtories. In another case, it might be that they forgot to remove a record of a person who is no longer there and you can ask for a fixed file and go on happily with your current process.